# Handle startActivityForResult data between multiple activities

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I am calling `Login.class` from fragment with `startActivityForResult(Login.class, 1)`. If user login successful then i am setting result as 1 else 0. Now, if user goes on `Register.class` from `Login.class` and comes back to `Login.class` then now, on successfull login, It is always returning result as 1.
**Check my below sample code :**

**MyAccount.java**

```
onCreate
Intent intLogin = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(intLogin, 1);

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(resultCode),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Login.java**

```
tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intRegister = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intRegister);

                finish();
            }
        });
on successfull Login :
setResult(1)
```

So, here it works fine if I don't click on `tvRegister` and it returns 0. If I clicks and go on new activity then it doesn't work and it returns 1.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you need to delete finish(); from tvRegister onClick

Comment: two point you should remember 1- in your fragment you should call getActivity().startActivityForResult() & 2-don't call super.onActivityResult()

Comment: @gabber, if i dnt call `finish();` then it wont clear that activity.

Comment: @Amir, let me try if it solves my problem.

Comment: @Amir, both options are not working.